# XNA - 2D collision failure without any obvious pattern

Tags: c#, xna, collision

Alright, so I am pretty new to XNA programming and I am trying to code a platformer. I have implemented pixel-perfect collision but it seems to fail for no apparent reason sometimes (I couldn't figure out a pattern) and the hero sprite goes through platforms.

```
static bool IntersectsPixel(Rectangle rect1, Color[] data1, Rectangle rect2, Color[] data2)
    {
        int top = Math.Max (rect1.Top, rect2.Top);
        int bottom = Math.Min(rect1.Bottom, rect2.Bottom);
        int left = Math.Max (rect1.Left,rect2.Left);
        int right = Math.Min(rect1.Right,rect2.Right);


        //Top
        for(int y = top; y<bottom;y++)
            for (int x = left; x < right; x++)
            {
                Color color1 = data1[x-rect1.Left + (y-rect1.Top) * rect1.Width];

                Color color2 = data2[x - rect2.Left + (y - rect2.Top) * rect2.Width];

                if (color1.A != 0 && color2.A != 0)
                    return true;
            }



        return false;
    }
```

And here's the Update Method

```
     protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();


       foreach(Platform platform in platformList)
       {
           Rectangle check = new Rectangle(hero.GetRectangle().X - 300, hero.GetRectangle().Y - 300, 600, 600);
            if(check.Intersects(platform.rectangle))
           if (IntersectsPixel(hero.GetRectangle(), hero.textureData, platform.rectangle, platform.platformTextureData))
           {
               int direction = CheckDirection(platform,hero);
               if (hero.hasJumped == true && direction == 3 && hero.velocity.Y <= 0 )
                   {
                         hero.velocity.Y = 0f;
                         hero.SetPosition(new Vector2((float)hero.GetPosition().X, (float)platform.rectangle.Bottom));


                       break;
                   }
               else
               if (direction == 4 && hero.velocity.X >= 0)
               {
                   hero.velocity.X = 1;
                   hero.SetPosition(new Vector2((float)platform.rectangle.Left - (float)hero.GetRectangle().Width, (float)hero.GetPosition().Y));
                   break;
               }
               else
                   if (direction == 2 && hero.velocity.X <= 0)
                   {
                       hero.velocity.X = -1;

                       hero.SetPosition(new Vector2((float)platform.rectangle.Right - 1, (float)hero.GetPosition().Y));
                       break;
                   }
                   else

               if (direction == 1 && hero.velocity.Y >= 0)
               {
                   hero.velocity.Y = 0;
                   hero.hasJumped = false;
                   hero.SetPosition(new Vector2((float)hero.GetRectangle().X, (float)platform.rectangle.Y - (float)hero.GetRectangle().Height + 1));
                   hero.SetRectangle(new Rectangle((int)hero.GetPosition().X, (int)hero.GetPosition().Y, (int)hero.GetSize().X, (int)hero.GetSize().Y));
                   break;
               }




               }


           }


        hero.Update(gameTime);
        camera.Update(gameTime, hero, screenBounds);
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

And here's the direction check:

```
     private int CheckDirection(Platform platform,Hero hero)
    {
        int distance = Math.Abs(platform.rectangle.Top - hero.GetRectangle().Bottom);
        int direction = 1; //Top
        if (distance > Math.Abs(platform.rectangle.Right - hero.GetRectangle().Left))
        {
            distance = Math.Abs(platform.rectangle.Right - hero.GetRectangle().Left);
            direction = 2;
        }
        if (distance > Math.Abs(platform.rectangle.Bottom - hero.GetRectangle().Top))
        {
            distance = Math.Abs(platform.rectangle.Bottom - hero.GetRectangle().Top);
            direction = 3;
        }
        if (distance > Math.Abs(platform.rectangle.Left - hero.GetRectangle().Right))
        {
            direction = 4;
            distance = Math.Abs(platform.rectangle.Left - hero.GetRectangle().Right);
        }
        return direction;
    }
```

Those are all my functions related to collision detection. If you happen to have any ideea of what might cause this, please let me know.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see that might be a possible reason is that right in the beginning where you build a box around both objects:

```
    int top = Math.Max (rect1.Top, rect2.Top);
    int bottom = Math.Min(rect1.Bottom, rect2.Bottom);
    int left = Math.Max (rect1.Left,rect2.Left);
    int right = Math.Min(rect1.Right,rect2.Right);
```

Unless you flipped it, typically XNA's Y grows positive as you go down (not up). This means you would actually want to take the Max of Bottom, and the Min of Top, since Top will always be less than Bottom. It looks like you already knew that though by the look of this line:

```
    for(int y = top; y<bottom;y++)
```

I'll keep looking (it's difficult to test without the actual project). Another recommendation I'd give you is to do some debug drawing. Draw where the intersection functions thinks that pixels are touching or not touching.

Comment: First of all thanks for your response. It'd be pretty weird to swap top and bottom Max/Min functions since those lines are taking the bounding box of the intersection. I will try it anyway since I might have gone wrong on paper. Also, I am a bit unsure on how should I go about debug drawing since I am not that used to using XNA, and quite new to programming as well. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Because of lag, Your character could be moving more than the blocks height per frame, so the collision may think it is in between blocks, and cause it to fly through.

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/30458/platformer-starter-kit-collision-issues

Check that out, It solved the problem for me.

Either slowing down movement, or clamping the change in position to the size of a block should solve this.